# Dual boot access windows partition through virtual box

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox

So I have a dual-boot system running windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I have separated them by partitioning.

I have certain programs and files on the windows partition that I need from time to time and it's a hassle to shut down Ubuntu and reboot into windows, especially if i have terminals and programs open with states I don't want to close and re-open.

So my question is: Is it possible to boot the windows partition in a VBox while using Ubuntu? And if it is, how do I do this?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible with [KVM](https://k3a.me/boot-windows-partition-virtually-kvm-uefi/) (reproduced below). You will need an UEFI implementation which you can download and there are a bunch of options you need to set for `qemu`. The following should work on Intel chipsets with sound. You probably want to test without sound and networking first.

**WARNING: do not attempt to boot your host OS or its drive in the VM or bad things will happen!**

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -cpu host -m 2048 -smp 3 -mem-path /dev/hugepages \
-display sdl -vga qxl \
-device qemu-xhci,id=xhci \
-device virtio-tablet,wheel-axis=true \
-soundhw hda \
-netdev user,id=vmnic,smb=/temp \
-device virtio-net,netdev=vmnic \
-drive file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,readonly=on \
-drive file=$HOME/.config/qemu-windows.nvram,if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1 \
-drive file=/dev/sdb,index=0,media=disk,driver=raw \
-cdrom /opt/UefiShell.iso
```

> For now I use sudo, because QEMU needs to access raw partitions from
>   `/dev/sdb`. The other, better way would be assigning a group to
>   `/dev/sdb`, setting up proper group permissions and adding me to that
>   group.
>
> `-m 2048 -smp 3` says to allocate 2GB of RAM for the guest and use 3 CPU cores
>
> `-mem-path /dev/hugepages` is better described in [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM#Enabling_huge_pages).
>
> `-display sdl -vga qxl` Use SDL for rendering and window management in the host and QXL GPU device in the guest (there are QXL drivers for
>   Windows).
>
> `-device qemu-xhci,id=xhci` Enable USB3 support by emulating an XHCI controller
>
> `-device virtio-tablet,wheel-axis=true` Emulate a tablet pointing device with mouse scroll support
>
> `-soundhw hda` Emulate Intel HD Audio
>
> netdev stuff Is for setting up network interface
>
> `-drive file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd,if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,readonly=on`
>   This is a very important part. It loads OVMF UEFI firmware read-only
>   as the first Flash device. This firmware implements a UEFI bios and
>   allows running UEFI Shell or booting .efi bootloader for Windows
>   (bootmgfw.efi). This OVMF can be downloaded directly from the [OVMF
>   project repo](https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/OVMF) or if you are using Arch Linux, just install ovmf
>   package.
>
> `-drive file=$HOME/.config/qemu-windows.nvram,if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1` this
>   loads a read-write NVRam flash image as the second virtual flash chip.
>   OVMF firmware uses this to store UEFI variables, .efi boot order, etc.
>   The default image can be copied from the OVMF setup (at
>   `/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_VARS.fd` in ovmf Arch linux package). It must
>   be a writable copy.
>
> `-drive file=/dev/sdb,index=0,media=disk,driver=raw` Attaches my raw sdb block device to the virtual machine. That is used as a HDD for the
>   guest, it has Windows pre-installed there together with EFI partition.
>
> -cdrom /opt/UefiShell.iso UEFI shell iso as a CDROM. Before OVMF nvram is properly configured to boot Windows by default, this will result in
>   booting into the EFI shell which allows to run .efi executables
>   manually. Windows can be run by just navigating into the EFI partition
>   and running the Windows efi loader –
>   `blkX:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`.
>
> I don’t know how to force Windows to write UEFI boot order. There
>   doesn’t seem to be a tool like efibootmgr on Windows. :D Windows would
>   set the UEFI boot order up randomly during some Windows Updates
>   (mostly when you don’t want it to touch your EFI setup). It eventually
>   set the EFI config up for me itself quite quickly. But if it fails,
>   you can try pressing ESC during TianoCore EFI boot to get to boot
>   menu. Or you can always boot Linux using the -cdrom command and use
>   efibootmgr to force the OVMF to boot the Windows loader entry for this
>   virtual machine by default. Usage of the efibootmgr command is out of
>   scope of this article and can be found in many online resources
>   elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I did not know, but it seems to be possible to do this in [VirtualBox](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/using-a-physical-hard-drive-with-a-virtualbox-vm.html) as well:

> You'll first want to create a virtual machine within the VirtualBox
>   GUI. Choose all options like normal, but when asked about the virtual
>   hard drive, select Do not add a virtual hard drive.

Issue fdisk to list the partitions and find the Windows partition:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Assuming `/dev/sda`

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "</path/to/file>.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda1
```

**WARNING: do not attempt to boot your host OS or mount its partition in the VM or bad things will happen!**

Comment: Tried this (just for fun) but got error: `Cannot open the raw disk '/dev/sdb2': VERR_ACCESS_DENIED`. It needs `sudo` (and then change ownership of the file).

Comment: Oh, I forgot, do this: `ls -l /dev/sda` assuming that sda is the device, you should see something like `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8...` <--- here the group is `disk`. `sudo usermod -a -G disk <myusername>` where `<myusername>` is your username, say, `jdoe`. This also works for the KVM solution, BTW.

Comment: But even after changing ownership of the created VMDK it gives the same error when trying to add it.

Comment: check permissions to  all files involved, what are the privs on the `vmdk` ? In fact, in the example above, you should do `ls -l /dev/sdb`

Comment: Please ignore. Something weird happened but it must be something to do with my system. To test this I installed Virtualbox in MATE and noticed it wasn't showing up in the menu (but opened in cli so I thought it was fine) and then proceeded to test your answer. Whatever that was after rebooting Virttualbox showed in MATE's menu and I could add the VDMK.

Comment: However, it doesn't work in the end. It doesn't boot with "EFI support" and without it boots to a blinking cursor. The "raw guest" Win10 as well as the Ubuntu Mate host are installed in UEFI mode so I assumed the VM would need it but either way it doesn't work. Hopefully your other solution with QEMU works, otherwise my short answer in comments still stands, unfortunately (for the OP).

Comment: It should work, though: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7702